# How to let ranger use zsh in default

Tags: linux, terminal

How could i make the terminal tool ("ranger") use zsh in default?
That means when i input command "S" ranger will back into zsh  while not bash

I haven't found the configuration method

Answer (score 0):

Configure the use of `zsh` in your ranger configuration.

```bash
echo "export SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh" >> ~/.config/ranger/rc.conf
```

Once you launch ranger, press `s`.